# Is it possible to split maven pom files?

Tags: maven-2

Is it possible to include several smaller pom files to create the parent pom file. (e.g. I would like to split the reporting, build sections into their own poms and include them in the parent pom) for managing them effectively

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are using Maven 2, you can simply create several parent levels. The first `pom.xml` (*pom1*) will define the basic properties (such as repositories for example). The second `pom.xml` (*pom2*), which has *pom1* as `<parent>`, will define the reporting information. And so on... Finally, the "real" `pom.xml` will inherit from the *pom2* and will define its own properties.

You can create as many parent levels as you want (of course, it will be harder to maintain if you have 5 parent levels).

Note that Maven 3 talked about introducing the [mixin concept](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2008/11/maven-project-model/), which will allow you to fragment your `pom.xml` into several files, but it looks like [that is not happening now until maven 4](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5102)

Comment: Guess, I will wait for the mixin feature in Maven 3

Comment: @Joshua Maven 3 is already available, even if it is a beta release, it is quite stable. Maven 3 offer a 100% compatibility with Maven 2 `pom.xml`. It is already used by the latest versions of NetBeans, m2eclipse or IntelliJ.

Comment: Maven 3.0 doesn't offer mixins *yet*, however.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Sorry for that !

Comment: @BrettPorter does the latest version (3.04) of maven support mixin?

Comment: Everything's cool, but the first paragraph is such a good example of a description that fits better into a diagram.

Comment: Forgive me for being naïve, but I would love to see an example for what has been mentioned here for Maven 2. Like a little before and after example.

Answer (score 5):

Not quite. You can't include reporting and build sections defined in smaller POMs, you can only [inherit them from a parent POM](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance).
If your POM is getting too large, it is possible (and recommended) to arrange your dependencies into logical groups. For example, for a GWT project, you could create a new POM for all of your persistence related to GWT as follows:

```
<project>
  <groupId>org.yourcompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwt-dependencies</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.extjs</groupId>
      <artifactId>gxt</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- etc -->
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

These groups can then be included in your main POM.

Comment: Also see: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html

Answer (score 2):

More recently, the option of using [Maven Tiles](http://repaint.io/) has become possible. The plugin will allow you to perform the mixin operations not provided by Maven 3. However, each mixin requires a released tile artefact.